# Returned value from a jquery ajax call

Tags: jquery, ajax, return

sHow can I use the value returned form a ajax call

my php file echos out yes or no...

```
if(mysqli_num_rows($checklogin) == 1)
    {
        $_SESSION['LoggedIn'] = 1;
        echo "yes";
       exit();
    }

    else {
      echo "no";
       exit();
    }
```

in my ajax I would like to do some jquery but how can I test for a positive result? This does not work.

```
$.ajax({ url: 'checklogin.php',
         data: {username: name, password: pass},
        dataType: 'text',
         type: 'post',
         success: function(output, status, jqXHR) {
           console.log(output);
            if (output == "yes") {
              console.log('yeeeeesss');
              $('form').hide();
            }

            else if (output =="no") {
                 console.log('nooooooo'); 
            }

                  }
});
```

EDIT if I return 1 and 0 from the php and then do

```
 if (parseInt(output) == 1) {
              console.log('yeeeeesss');

            }

            else if (parseInt(output) == 0) {
                 console.log('nooooooo'); 
            }

                  }
```

It works, must be to do with the returned output, although **console.log(jQuery.type(output))** returns a string.

Comment: What browser console tells?

Comment: it the value of the php echoed value so either 'yes' or 'no'. It's the logic inside the success function that gets ignored.

Comment: You should try `return "Yes"` instead echo in PHP file!

Comment: no does no return anything.

Comment: Not very familiar with PHP so hard to tell you what to return. What is output right now? Is it blank?